# How to create a panda/pickle dataset wtih np arrays entries in columns so that I can plot them efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, dataset

I have a list of dictionaries in python with values both floats and np arrays. I want to save it in a pandas dataframe so that I can plot the xarr, yarr for a given set of parameters.

```
dic1 = {'p1':1, 'p2': 34, 'xarr' : np.array([1,2,3]) , 'yarr': np.array([4,4,6])}
dic2 = {'p1':2, 'p2': 45 ,'xarr' : np.array([1,2,3]) , 'yarr': np.array([6,6,4])}
listdic = [dic1, dic2]
df = pd.DataFrame(listdic)
dfplot= df[df['p1'] > 1]
x, y = dfplot['xarr'], dfplot['yarr']
plt.plot(x, y)
```

But I get this error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Because I am also getting the index of the pandas df.
Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting `dataframe` you have created looks like this:

[image]

When you ask for: `x, y = dfplot['xarr'], dfplot['yarr']`, you are asking for the content of the columns `xarr` & `yarr` which both contains lists.
Thus for each of them you are getting a [series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) of lists.

See for yourself:
`type(x)` Will result:

> pandas.core.series.Series

You can access the series content using [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
idx = 0
x = x_series.iloc[idx]
```

In your example you have only 1 record so you can simply use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dic1 = {'p1':1, 'p2': 34, 'xarr' : np.array([1,2,3]) , 'yarr': np.array([4,4,6])}
dic2 = {'p1':2, 'p2': 45 ,'xarr' : np.array([1,2,3]) , 'yarr': np.array([6,6,4])}
listdic = [dic1, dic2]
df = pd.DataFrame(listdic)
dfplot= df[df['p1'] > 1]
x_series, y_series = dfplot['xarr'], dfplot['yarr']
x,y = x_series.iloc[0], y_series.iloc[0]
plt.plot(x, y)
```